# String being sent unrecognized selector in multiple section table view

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I recieve a *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString username]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e2460'
*** First throw call stack:

This error originates from

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFUser *friend = nil;
    if ([self.friendList count]> indexPath.row){
        friend =[self.friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    PFUser *acceptedFriend = nil;
    if ([self.accepted count] > indexPath.row){
       acceptedFriend = [self.accepted objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            if ([self.friendList count] > indexPath.row){
            cell.textLabel.text = friend.username;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text= friend.email;
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            if ([self.accepted count] >indexPath.row){
            //APP crashes here
            cell.textLabel.text = acceptedFriend.username;
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = acceptedFriend.email;
            cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Treehouse.png"];
            }
        default:
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Nothing Here";
            break;
    }
    // Configure the cell...


    return cell;
}
```

The crash points to the instance of cell.textLabel.text = acceptedFriend.username;

The viewDidAppear method is where the query from parse occurs and the data source is set up with the data from parse.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    /*
    PFRelation *friendRelation = [self.currentUser relationForKey:@"friendRelation"];
    PFQuery *existingFriends = [friendRelation query];
    [existingFriends findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
            self.friendList = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
     */

    PFQuery *userQuary = [PFUser query];
    PFQuery *acceptedQuary = [PFUser query];
    PFQuery *pendingFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    PFQuery *aceptedFriends = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendRequest"];
    [aceptedFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [aceptedFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Accepted"];
    [acceptedQuary whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"fromUser" inQuery:aceptedFriends];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" doesNotMatchKey:@"status" inQuery:aceptedFriends];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"toUser" equalTo:self.currentUser.objectId];
    [pendingFriends whereKey:@"status" equalTo:@"Pending"];
    [userQuary whereKey:@"objectId" matchesKey:@"fromUser" inQuery:pendingFriends];
    [userQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
            self.friendList = objects;

            //delte me
            //self.accepted =objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.friendList);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];

    [acceptedQuary findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }else{
       self.accepted = objects;
            NSLog(@"%@", self.accepted);
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];



}
```

I have also loged the data and it does have the username data key within objects.

EDIT: 
I have setup now both of the sections to display the same data and now I am recieving an *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array' *** First throw call stack: error. Its happening around the

```
  PFUser *acceptedFriend = nil;
    if ([self.accepted count] > indexPath.row){
       acceptedFriend = [self.friendList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Its happening in the method named
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: The error indicates that `acceptedFriend` is actually an `NSString`, not a `PFUser`. Check what's really in your `self.accepted` array.

Comment: It seems like your acceptedFriend does not have the property 'username'. Are you 100% sure that your acceptedFriend is a PFUser?

Comment: In Query, it returns NSArray of PFObject, so I think you need to warp it to PFUser or use [acceptedFriend objectForKey:@"username"]; instead

Comment: I have set up breakpoints and noticed that Im not recieving an NSLog of any kind to even verify if I have data within the arrays.

Comment: Edit the question with the new data source.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you that you're trying to call the `username` method on a `NSString` object. You're calling `username` in two cases, either for `friend` or `acceptedfriend`. So, you should confirm which of these two lines is causing the problem (you can do this by adding an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html)).

You can then confirm:

- that the object you're retrieving from the array is really a `NSString` object rather than a `PFUser` object with the `username` and `email` properties; and
- then you can go about confirming why your array has strings rather than your custom object.

You're logging `friendlist` and `accepted` arrays in your `viewDidLoad`. Do these arrays look OK there (i.e. are they arrays of custom objects or are they simple `NSString` objects)?

Comment: Not getting an NSlog back even.

Comment: @TheM00s3 So, you're hitting the line of code that logs of `self.accepted` and `self.friendList`, and you're seeing it log, for example, an empty array? Then `friend` and `acceptedFriend` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be `nil`, no?

Comment: I have edited my original question and shown where the error occurs around to now with the new data source.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your tableView is loaded at viewDidLoad and the data is coming to your string at viewDidAppear. The solution would be that, you have to try loading tableView only if you are having data to load that is you get details from parse. For this, in numberOfRows method you can return 0 initially and once you get details you can return the details array count.(just for example)

Comment: Check out the new edits. I'm wondering how to add protections.